# Google Elevation API - splitting multiple elevation requests

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to split a big request for elevation into multiple requests to avoid the 1sec/request and 512 coords limit in each request.

The problem I face is that the reply of my requests are not always received in the good order.  Is using setInterval reliable enough?
Here is an example of response received in the wrong order that cause a problem (before using setInterval):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x00jdnprj6w7lga/correctMap.png?dl=0

Here is my latest code:

```js
function getCourseElevationData() {

    var path = bikePathCoordinates; //Bunch of lat,long coords
//  numberRequestToDo = Math.ceil(path.length/512); //TODO: split request in multiple 512 pack (google quotas)
    numberRequestToDo = 2; //Temporary for testing
    currentRequestNumber = -1; //will be at 0 on first call to get512Elevation
    arrayOfRequest = [];

    //1
    var ptrStart= 0;
    var pathSliced = path.slice(ptrStart, ptrStart+512);
    arrayOfRequest.push(pathSliced);

    //2
    ptrStart += 512;
    pathSliced = path.slice(ptrStart, ptrStart+512);
    arrayOfRequest.push(pathSliced);

    timerElevation = setInterval(request512Elevation, 1000);  //1sec
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
function request512Elevation() {

    alert("request512Elevation");

    // Still has request to be done
    if (currentRequestNumber+1 < numberRequestToDo) {

        if (!lastRequestElevationFailed) {
            currentRequestNumber++;
        }
        get512Elevation(arrayOfRequest[currentRequestNumber], currentRequestNumber);
    }
    // All request completed!
    else {
        clearInterval(timerElevation);
    }
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function get512Elevation(pathSliced, requestNumber) {

    alert("get512PointsElevation" + requestNumber);

    var locationElevationRequest = {
            'locations': pathSliced
            }

    elevator.getElevationForLocations(locationElevationRequest, function (results, status) {

        alert("ResponseReceived for request:" + requestNumber + ", status" + status + " result length:" +  results.length);
        if (status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
            lastRequestElevationFailed = true;
            return;
        }
        lastRequestElevationFailed = false;
        var elevations = results;
        // Extract the elevation samples from the returned results
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
         elevationPath.push(elevations[i].location);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            dataElevation.addRow(['', elevations[i].elevation]);
        }

        //last reply received? if yes, we can display the elevation graph
        if (currentRequestNumber+1 == numberRequestToDo) {
            chart.draw(dataElevation, chartOptions);
        }
        //TODO: how to make sure response are received in correct order (1,2,3)? setInterval reliable enough?
     });
}
```

Comment: My first thought would be to use function closure to associate the request with the response.  Do you have sample data that shows the issue?

Comment: Here is an example of the result with 2 requests of 512 coordinates that worked: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x00jdnprj6w7lga/correctMap.png?dl=0
Here is a file example I'm using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bs07ljow1omxc8m/5150_Tremblant_2015.gpx?dl=0
It seems sometime only the first request suceed, and the second doesn't trigger a callback, I'm thinking it may be due to the quotas and making request too fast, trying to find a way to sleep for 1 sec between each request.  I want to show the graph only when the last request was completed, but i'm not sure how to identify this like you mention.

Comment: I have updated my code up there with a solution I took from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066092/how-to-handle-multiple-requests-to-the-google-api-google-maps-distancematrixserv Now I just need to figure out how to make sure each request succeed (retry if it failed), and add a delay between request to avoid google 1sec/request limitation. Not sure on the best way to put a delay, a busy while loop that wait for the last callback to succeed seems like a bad idea..

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have been able to solve the callback issue this way.  1- Keep track of the response that have been completed with success 2- do not try another request if the one before is not yet completed.

Comment: I was facing sort of a similar issue and fixed it with a timer and processing boolean to assure a request has completed before proceeding to the next, but am now experiencing inaccurate placement of markers for the elevation. Have you been faced with this as well?